# How to create a file with initial size 4KB filled with zeros?

Tags: java, file, byte

As the title says, I want to create a new file and set its initial size to 4 Kbytes, and those 4 Kbytes are all zeros (0). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well depending on the encoding of the text file (ASCII, utf-8 etc), character size will be 1 - 3 bytes per char. You want 1024 * 4 bytes for a 4KB file...

Comment: What sort of Java code have you tried already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a 4Kb array, and write it to file.

```
byte[] b = new byte[4096];
```

This will create a 4096 element array (4 x 1024), with each element as a 0.

Then write it to file.

```
try (FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream("/path/to/file"))
{
    stream.write(b);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simple create a `byte` array of size `4096` and write it to your file as follows:

1. Using `FileOutputStream`

   ```
   FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream("/home/usr/...");
   fo.write(new byte[4096]);
   fo.close();
   ```
2. Using Apache Commons

   ```
   FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File("/home/usr/..."), new byte[4096]);
   ```